# Visual Basic Script simple time elapsed

Tags: vbscript

I want to show message to user when 3 minutes passed in VBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean that you want the script to wait for 3 minutes and then show a messagebox? If so try this:

```
WScript.Sleep(180000)
MsgBox("Your 3 minutes are up, we're all going to die!")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing shell scripting, the following will work

```
WScript.Sleep 500 'this parameter is in milliseconds, this is 1/2 a second.
MsgBox "OK"
```

If you're doing web dev, you're better off using javascript

```
setTimeout("alert('OK')",500); //this is milliseconds again
```